# Linkify Android for phone numbers, address and Email

Tags: android, linkify

I have a custom `TextView` (extends `TextView`) which can contain any text configured by the customer. I need to add the functionality, where user can click the phone number, address and email and app can launch appropriate app (dialer, maps, email). Please look my current implementation :

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{        

    // constructors and styling of this view

   public void setStyle(){
        setLinksClickable(true);
        setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        Linkify.addLinks(this, Linkify.ALL);
       //setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
   }

}
```

1. What is wrong in my implementation ? I cannot click the text containing the phone number, address and email.
2. What format for phone number, address and email should be inputted in the textview for this feature to work ?

Any help or advise appreciated !!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Linky.addLinks(this, Linkify.ALL)` after the text has been set, not in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, the above lines were added after setting the text. Please check my edits above.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I added `android:autoLink="all"` to the `TextView` element in xml. My phone number format in the `TextView` was incorrect. These are some of phone number formats supported by `Linkify`: 12345678912, +12345678912, 1-234-567-8912, +1-234-567-8912, (1234) 567-8912, +(1234) 567-8912.

Note : There could be more supported formats too !!

Thanks